# Xamarin.IOs CollectionViewCell needs to have a constructor with IntPtr to avoid 'Failed to marshal the Objective-C object' error

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my Xamarin.IOs project, I have a Collection Cell class (**CollectionViewCell**)

```
public class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    //
}
```

that provides cell views for a UICollectionView. I get an error,

```
Failed to marshal the Objective-C ... Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'CollectionViewCell' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).
```

if I don't give a constructor like,

```
public CollectionViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
    //
}
```

for this Cell view class. But my problem is, I need to use Dependency injection for this Cell view class (**CollectionViewCell**). For example,

```
public CollectionViewCell(ViewServices services, IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
    //
}
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Have you solved your issues?

Comment: I took the approach of taking an instance of ViewServices within the CollectionViewCell. I use lightinject for Dependency Injection.

Ex: Inside the constructor of CollectionViewCell,

`m_viewService = s_container.GetInstance<ViewServices>();`

Answer (score 0):

`public CollectionViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)` will be automatically called when you use **Storyboard** or **xib** to initialize the cell's instance. We should not modify it by adding more parameters.

If you want to use user interface to construct a control, the corresponding cs file should contain this construction method.

In your case, you want to pass some parameters to the cell. You can do that after the cell has created in the event `GetCell()`:

```
CustomCollectionViewCell cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell", indexPath) as CustomCollectionViewCell;
// Do some configuration here (cell.DoSettings(...))
return cell;
```

In the cell's cs class you can export a function like:

```
public void DoSettings(ViewServices services)
{

}
```